# Using Python-MIP to represent continuous work in a work schedule

Tags: python, pulp

I would like to use Python-MIP to create a work schedule, but I don't know how to represent consecutive workdays, so I would like to ask a question.

I created a dateframe in pandas from the workers (Yamada, Tanaka, Takahashi, Sato), the date, and the work details (A to G), and I wanted to calculate whether or not each of the workdays would be worked on that day by using 0 and 1 variables.
The number of days for each workday is defined, and the information is contained in a dictionary.
The following is the dateframe I created.

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd
from pulp import *
from ortoolpy import addvars, addbinvars
import openpyxl
from mip import *
from more_itertools import pairwise, windowed

member_list = [ 'Yamada', 'Tanaka', 'Takahasi',  'Satou']
work_list = [ "A", "B", "C", "D","E","F","G","rest"]
work_list_none_rest =  [ "A", "B", "C", "D","E","F","G"]
date_list = range(1,30)

date_dict =[{'name': 'Yamada', 'A': 6, 'B': 6, 'C': 6, 'D': 6, 'E': 5, 'F': 0, 'G': 0},
{'name': 'Tanaka', 'A': 6, 'B': 6, 'C': 6, 'D': 6, 'E': 5, 'F': 0, 'G': 0},
{'name': 'Takahasi', 'A': 6, 'B': 6, 'C': 6, 'D': 6, 'E': 5, 'F': 0, 'G': 0},
{'name': 'Satou', 'A': 6, 'B': 6, 'C': 6, 'D': 6, 'E': 5, 'F': 0, 'G': 0}]

member_day = []
new_member_day = []

for d in date_list:
    for i in member_list:
        for c in work_list:
            test = [i,int(d),c]
            member_day.append(test)
            test = []

df = pd.DataFrame(member_day,columns = ["member","date","work"])

m = Model()
df["Var"] =  m.add_var_tensor((len(df),), "Var", var_type=BINARY)
```

The constraints for the work you want to create are as follows

1. Each day must be one of the following workdays: A to G or Vacation.
2. The maximum number of people who can work A-G in a day is 3 (there is no limit on the minimum number).
3. Each employee must work the number of days specified in A through G.
4. Workdays A through G must be consecutive (e.g., if Yamada works A on the first day, he works A from the first day to the sixth day because A is six days in Yamada's case).

I was able to create constraints for 1. to 3. with the following code, but I could not figure out how to give constraints for work that spans multiple days, such as 4.

```
#Each person will work once per day.
for _,gr in df.groupby(["member","date"]):
    m += xsum(gr.Var) == 1

#The maximum number of people per shift is three per day.
for _,gr in df.groupby("date"):
    m += xsum(gr[gr.work == "A"].Var) <= 3
    m += xsum(gr[gr.work == "B"].Var) <= 3
    m += xsum(gr[gr.work == "C"].Var) <= 3
    m += xsum(gr[gr.work == "D"].Var) <= 3
    m += xsum(gr[gr.work == "E"].Var) <= 3
    m += xsum(gr[gr.work == "F"].Var) <= 3
    m += xsum(gr[gr.work == "G"].Var) <= 3

#Work a set number of shifts per worker.
for name, gr in df.groupby("member"):
    for x in date_dict:
        if name == x['name']:
            for i in work_list_none_rest:
                m += xsum(gr[gr.work == i].Var) == x[i]

m.verbose = 0
m.optimize()

df["Val"] = df.Var.astype(float)
res = df[df.Val > 0]
res_order = { "A": 1, "B": 2,  "C": 3 ,"D": 4, "E":5,"F":6,"G":7}
res = res[res.work != "none"]
res['order'] = res['work'].map(res_order)
res = res.sort_values(['date','order'])
res.to_excel('test_list.xlsx')
```

I thought it might be better to use a function like windowed, but it didn't work.

```
#Work the same shift consecutively.
for _,gr in df.groupby(["member","work"]):
    for x in date_dict:
        if name == x['name']:
            for i in work_list_none_rest:
                Q = "date in @dd and work =='{}'".format(i)
                m += xsum([gr.query(Q).Var for dd in windowed(date_list,6)]) == 1

#TypeError: type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> not supported
```

How do I express the constraint? Also, if this DateFrame and variables are not enough, how can I create a DateFrame?
If possible, I would like to create such a model where the number of days per shift can be kept the same, but with a break between each shift.
For example, if the workday for A is 6 days, you can do A for 3 days, then take a break, then start working A for 3 days the next day, and so on....

Comment: You will probably need to introduce an additional binary variable that represents the decision to start a series of work events on one particular day and then link the subsequent days to that variable with constraints.  You'll probably be happier if you get out of "data frame" mindset and set up index sets, etc for clarity.